# Are global validations for multiple attributes in a model class possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets take this example Model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :postcode, :street, :number
  validates :city, presence: true, size: {minimum: 2}
  validates :postcode, presence: true
  validates :street, presence: true 
  validates :number, presence: true  
end
```

Do i have to make all validations for each attribute separate? All attributes here have one common validation `presence: true`. Can´t I write something like `validates * , presence: true`

Hope you understand what I mean. There should be a solution, as rails and ruby often talk about the DRY way ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validates_presence_of :city, :street, :postcode, :number
```

Comment: Thx. Another question: In the link below, they say that validates_presence_of attributes is the default setting on save. Is that true? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_presence_of

Comment: I don't think so, at least in rails 3+